# Calculating the working days between two dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my function where i tried to calculate the number of working days between two dates.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function workingdays 
( start_date IN DATE , end_date IN DATE)

return  number

as

total_days varchar2(10);

v_count integer:= 0;

end_value date := to_date(end_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD');

start_value date := to_date(start_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD');

date_diff number(10);


begin

while(start_value <= end_value)

loop

        if (to_char(TO_DATE(start_value,'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'D') = 1 or to_char(TO_DATE(start_value,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'D') = 7)
        then v_count := v_count+1;
        end if;

start_value := start_value + 1;

end loop;

date_diff :=to_number( to_date( end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - to_date (start_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD')) ;

total_days := to_char( (to_number(date_diff) - to_number(v_count)) + 1);


return (' The total working days is' || to_number((total_days)));


end;
/
```

The function compiles successfully, but on executing it, I get an error message at the return line. Could someone guide me. It is some issue the number/character conversion.

Comment: you shoudl format your code better. [read here howto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Why do you return a string by concatenating a string and a to_number(string)?

Comment: You do not need to use to_date around variable that is already a date. In order to count working days you would have to use some sort of calendar - think about holidays. You did not count those. The error you are getting is due to the fact that you are returning string, not number. Variable total_days should really be number, and you should return total_days, and nothing else.

Comment: Not digging further in your code but it looks you are trying to return `varchar` in  `number`. The return type if the Function is `Number`. Correct that at first place. Secondly there is no need for explicit coversion while substraction. `date_diff := (TO_DATE (end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE (start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))` is enough to give you no. of day.

Comment: When you get an error message at the return line: What is the error message?

Comment: Why do you convert a `DATE` value into a `DATE` and `NUMBER` into `NUMBER`?

Comment: Regardless of the rest of the code: The function returns a `NUMBER` and that is **right**. Sending output to the screen from the function itself is wrong, except for debugging. At the end of the function, you should have `dbms_output.put_line('Total working days is' || total_days)`, and then, **separately**, `return total_days`. After you are satisfied that the function works correctly, you can delete the `put_line` command. If in the application of the function, the user needs to print the value, the user needs to write his/her/its own way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You make a lot of useless conversions, almost all of them can be skipped.

Result of `TO_CHAR(..., 'D')` depends on current user `NLS_TERRITORY` value, so you should not use it unless you ensure a certain `NLS_TERRITORY` setting.

This one is working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION workingdays(start_date IN DATE , end_date IN DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

    total_days NUMBER;
    v_count INTEGER:= 0;
    end_value DATE := TRUNC(end_date);
    start_value DATE := TRUNC(start_date);
    date_diff NUMBER;

BEGIN

    WHILE start_value <= end_value LOOP
        IF TO_CHAR(start_value, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 
            v_count := v_count + 1;
      END IF;
      start_value := start_value + 1;
    END LOOP;
    date_diff := end_value - TRUNC(start_date);
    total_days := date_diff - v_count + 1;

    RETURN ' The total working days is ' || total_days;

END;
/
```

There are many other possibilities, this is just another way of doing it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION workingdays(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    next_run_date DATE := TRUNC(start_date);
    total_days INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        EXIT WHEN next_run_date >= end_date;
        total_days := total_days + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ' The total working days is ' || total_days;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(a_day)
       as from_date
      ,max(a_day)
       as till_date
      ,sum(decode(to_char(a_day,'D')
                 ,1,0
                 ,7,0
                 ,1
                 )
          )
       as wrk_days_count   
from (select trunc(sysdate,'iw') + level - 1
             as a_day
      from dual
      connect by level < 8)
;
```

Comment: delete this as well as my user, ty ;-)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. If you want to delete it, there's a button for that next to the "share" and "edit" buttons below the post.